# Construct heatmap matrix with personal metric python

Tags: python, matrix, metrics, bleu

I want to construct a heatmap matrix but with a customized metric, which is the bleu score. I have 20 sentences that I want to compare this way.

I tried to use sns.heatmap or sns.clustermap and then to add sentence_bleu as a metric function, but get the error unknown metric function.

How can I define a usable customized metric?